# Sistema de comentário com chave estrangeira "autor_coment"

Tags: php, sql

Tem uma tabela comentarios com os seguintes atributos: id (`int not null`), comentario (`text not null`), data_coment (`timestamp not null`) e **autor_coment** (`int not null`).

O **autor_coment** é uma `FK` que referencia uma outra tabela do BD (`login`).

Estou tendo dificuldade para cadastrar o comentário, sendo que:

- Preciso verificar se o usuário está logado, senão ele não pode comentar.
- Preciso mostrar o nome do autor_coment e não o id

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Em que exatamente tu ta tendo dificuldade? Posta o código do que tu já fez até agora.

Comment: Sql Server ou MySql? Apresenta algum erro? poste o comando de insert que está fazendo

Answer (score 0):

Esse é o código de cadastro do comentário:

```
   <?php
include 'admin/conexao/conecta.php';

if(isset($_POST['comentar'])){
            $comentario = trim(strip_tags($_POST['comentario']));

$insert = "INSERT into comentarios (comentario) VALUES (:comentario)";

        try{
            $result = $conexao->prepare($insert);
            $result->bindParam(':comentario', $comentario, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $result->execute();
            $contar = $result->rowCount();
            if($contar>0){
                echo '';
            }else{
                echo '<script> alert("Erro ao comentar.") </script>';
            }           
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo $e;
        }

?>

<br>
<form method="post" action="#"> 
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b>Nome:</b> <br><input style="width: 200px;height: 40px;" type="text" id="autor_coment" name="autor_coment" placeholder="Digite seu nome">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-top: 10px;">
            <b>Comentário</b> <br>
            <textarea style="width: 500px; height: 150px;" type="text" id="comentario" name="comentario" required></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding-left: 295px;">
        <input class="w3-button w3-black w3-section" style="width:100px; height:40px; background:#333; color:white; border:none;" type="reset" name="cancelar" value="Cancelar"/>
        <input class="w3-button w3-black w3-section" style="width:100px; height:40px; background:#333; color:white; border:none;" type="submit" name="comentar" value="Comentar"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
<br>
```

O problema é que eu não faço ideia de como trabalhar com a `FK` `autor_coment` no cadastro.